# Generating a form with several long select elements is slow in Svelte

Tags: forms, svelte, html-select

I'm writing an app in Svelte, and I have a page on which there is a list of values displayed as a table. I want to be able to edit these values, and one of the values is chosen by a `select` element with about 100 possible values.

There is a button that toggles the display between table display and form edit mode (with the `select` elements).

The problem is that if there are several lines that create `select` items each with the same 100 possible option values, it takes Svelte a very long time to generate the form (about a full second to switch to edit mode when there are about 15 `select` elements). I didn't have this problem with React on the same app (I'm porting most of the app from React to Svelte) so I suppose there's something I'm doing wrong or that there is a suble way of making things faster...

Here's a small working example to illustrate :

```html
<script>
  const pokemonList = ["bulbasaur", "ivysaur", "venusaur", "charmander", "charmeleon", "charizard", "squirtle", "wartortle", "blastoise", "caterpie", "metapod", "butterfree", "weedle", "kakuna", "beedrill", "pidgey", "pidgeotto", "pidgeot", "rattata", "raticate", "spearow", "fearow", "ekans", "arbok", "pikachu", "raichu", "sandshrew", "sandslash", "nidoran-f", "nidorina", "nidoqueen", "nidoran-m", "nidorino", "nidoking", "clefairy", "clefable", "vulpix", "ninetales", "jigglypuff", "wigglytuff", "zubat", "golbat", "oddish", "gloom", "vileplume", "paras", "parasect", "venonat", "venomoth", "diglett", "dugtrio", "meowth", "persian", "psyduck", "golduck", "mankey", "primeape", "growlithe", "arcanine", "poliwag", "poliwhirl", "poliwrath", "abra", "kadabra", "alakazam", "machop", "machoke", "machamp", "bellsprout", "weepinbell", "victreebel", "tentacool", "tentacruel", "geodude", "graveler", "golem", "ponyta", "rapidash", "slowpoke", "slowbro", "magnemite", "magneton", "farfetchd", "doduo", "dodrio", "seel", "dewgong", "grimer", "muk", "shellder", "cloyster", "gastly", "haunter", "gengar", "onix", "drowzee", "hypno", "krabby", "kingler", "voltorb", "electrode", "exeggcute", "exeggutor", "cubone", "marowak", "hitmonlee", "hitmonchan", "lickitung", "koffing", "weezing", "rhyhorn", "rhydon", "chansey", "tangela", "kangaskhan", "horsea", "seadra", "goldeen", "seaking", "staryu", "starmie", "mr-mime", "scyther", "jynx", "electabuzz", "magmar", "pinsir", "tauros", "magikarp", "gyarados", "lapras", "ditto", "eevee", "vaporeon", "jolteon", "flareon", "porygon", "omanyte", "omastar", "kabuto", "kabutops", "aerodactyl", "snorlax", "articuno", "zapdos", "moltres", "dratini", "dragonair", "dragonite", "mewtwo", "mew"];

  let team = [
    "bulbasaur",
    "charmander",
    "squirtle",
    "caterpie",
    "weedle",
    "pidgey",
    "rattata",
    "spearow",
    "ekans",
    "pikachu",
    "sandshrew",
    "nidoran-f",
    "nidoran-m",
    "clefairy",
    "vulpix",
    "jigglypuff",
  ];

  let isEditing = false;
</script>

<main>
  {#if isEditing}
    <form>
      {#each team as teamMember}
        <div>
          <select bind:value={teamMember}>
            {#each pokemonList as pokemonName}
              <option value={pokemonName}>{pokemonName}</option>
            {/each}
          </select>
        </div>
      {/each}
    </form>
  {:else}
    <table>
      {#each team as teamMember}
        <tr>
          <td>{teamMember}</td>
        </tr>
      {/each}
    </table>
  {/if}
  <button on:click={() => (isEditing = !isEditing)}>Toggle</button>
</main>
```

Note that all the select that are generated have exactly the same list of options, so is there a way to generate the element once and reuse it each time? Or any other solution that would make this much more responsive? In the example, if I only keep one line then toggling to editing mode is almost instantaneous, but it takes significantly longer as more lines are added.

Comment: I wonder if the performance hit is also seen in Vanilla JS.  I think it would be worth creating a Vanilla JS project that does the same and see if this is a Svelte problem or not.  If Vanilla JS exhibits the same problem, I guess you're stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are various builds and that a development Svelte build will perform worse that a production build. Also SSR vs CSR can have different performance characteristics and different browsers handle large HTML fragments differently.

Your machine might be a bit underpowered or your browser might perform particularly badly; [your code in the REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9b620f1dc8bb471db3343a2cd3217c36?version=4.2.0) takes ~25ms on mine in Chrome or Firefox.

Still, this scenario can be optimized in at least two ways:

- Only show the select when interacting with that one specific item (e.g. on clicking on it) - [should be straightforward](https://svelte.dev/repl/6eacdf5eaa88409b834860c8f990db8b?version=4.2.0), not great UX
- Only generate the items in the lists, when they become relevant, i.e. focus is on the element

For the latter approach, you can separate the generation of the options into a separate component, e.g.

```html
<select bind:value={teamMember}>
  <LazyOptions list={pokemonList} value={teamMember} />
</select>
```

```html
<!-- LazyOptions.svelte -->
<script>
  export let list;
  export let value;

  let focused = false;

  function checkFocus(node) {
    const select = node.closest('select');

    const update = () => focused = document.activeElement == select;

    select.addEventListener('focus', update);
    select.addEventListener('blur', update);
    update();

    return {
      destroy() {
        select.removeEventListener('focus', update);
        select.removeEventListener('blur', update);
      },
    };
  }
</script>

<!-- Makes sure that the currently selected value always exists.
     Also provides an entry into the DOM to find the select. -->
<option style:display="none" use:checkFocus>{value}</option>

{#if focused}
  {#each list as o}
    <option>{o}</option>
  {/each}
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2292abcbfebe4847816810035d2f7f0a?version=4.2.0)

There are other ways of doing this, like passing in the focus state, but this way it is a bit more neatly encapsulated.

Comment: It turns out that it was a problem with a Chrome extension that was slowing down the appearance of forms (a password manager that parses each form field apparently). If I disable this extension there is no problem at all.
Thanks for the detailed answer with interesting pointers to different improvement techniques.